# Until flag not working with Until activity of ADF and loop keep going

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to execute Azure Durable Function in ADF.
I have "Get Current Function Status" Activity inside Until activity. Possible value are pending, completed, running and exception. I have variable until_flag which do get value "true" if runTimeStatus get value Completed.

My problem is that even runTimeStatus is completed Until loop never stop. It keeps going. What is wrong?

I'm following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aD3k8k5sdao

I have tried:

```
@equals(bool(variables('until_flag')), 'true')
```

and

```
@bool(variables('until_flag'))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: were you able to solve this from previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70757360/15969417)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the official MS docs on [UntilActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-until-activity)

> Enter an expression that will be evaluated after all child activities
> defined in the Until activity are executed. If the expression
> evaluates to false, the Until activity will execute all its child
> activities again. When it evaluates to true, the Until activity will
> complete. The expression can be a literal string expression, or any
> combination of dynamic expressions, functions, system variables, or
> outputs from other activities.

So try with this expression to evaluate condition

```
@equals(variables('until_flag'), 'false')
```

Comment: Still keep going on loop with @equals(bool(variables('until_flag')), 'false') even variable value got value true.

Comment: Can you try without the `bool` function as `@equals(variables('until_flag'), 'false')`

Comment: @equals(variables('until_flag'), 'false') and @equals(variables('until_flag'), 'true') Still going neverending loop even until_flag value got "true".

Comment: Still looping with @equals(variables('until_flag'), 'false') or @equals(variables('until_flag'), 'true')  The variable output is {"name": "until_flag", "value": true }

Comment: @equals(variables('until_flag'), true) worked fine.

Comment: awesome, it was considering 'true' as string i guess